# AngularJS custom directive and ctrl, throws error if: the method of ctrl is the same as name of ctrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am still new to AngularJS, so here is a problem I have to solve:

I made a custom submit directive that submits a form only if it is valid. 
It can be used like this:

`<form novalidate mm-submit="mySubmitMethod()">`

Everything works fine until I try a `RegisterCtrl` with a `register` method in it; on submission the directive throws the following error:

`TypeError: object is not a function
at ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js:9068:15`

If the method is named `register2` or something else everything works fine.

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdM7z8tHLUOHQFotndX3?p=preview) with demo and source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your form name is `register` that's binding a FormController to the `register` property on the parent scope. If you `console.log(scope.register)` within your directive you'll see the FormController there. If you don't create any isolated scope you'll need to define your submit function as something different or change your form name to prevent this clash.

Comment: 10x @eddiec it seems i need to learn more about isolated scope